# How to backup the XBMC database (Actor information, cover art...)

Tags: 12.04, xbmc

I am going to upgrade/fresh install my system from Ubuntu 32 Bit PAE to 64 Bit. Apart from many things I want to backup, there is one thing I really need to make sure that is correctly backed up. This is the XBMC cache. My connection is slow and I do not want to spend 3 days again downloading all the information. What do I need to backup in order to have this working again. Note the following:

1. The source of the movies will be in the same place. I will not change them. Right now they are in /media/movies for movies and /media/series for Tv series. They will still be like that once I update to 64 bit.
2. The .xbmc in my home folder is the only thing I think I need to backup but I want to be 100% sure.

What else do I need to backup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The XBMC database is fully stored within `~/.xbmc/userdata` and it *should* be sufficient to just archive `~/.xbmc` and restore it.
- However, for peace of mind, you may also want to consider using the [*XBMC:backup*](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Add-on%3aXBMC_Backup) plugin and exporting/importing the database.

Source: [XBMC Forums thread](http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=73680)